# Check if product exists in more than one category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, template, product-view

I have the following code in *view.phtml* that checks if a product is in a specific category (2495), and if it is, outputs some text.

**EXISTING CODE**

```
<?php if (Mage::registry('current_category') && Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 2495) { ?>
CONTENT GOES HERE...
<?php } ?>
```

How do I go about checking if the product exists in more than one category (e.g. 2495, 2496 & 2497)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$categoryIds = array(2495, 2496, ...);
if (Mage::registry('current_category') && in_array (Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(), $categoryIds)) {
     //code here
}
```

Comment: Final code I ended with is as follows...
<?php $categoryIds = array(2495, 1163); if (Mage::registry('current_category') && in_array (Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(), $categoryIds)) { ?>code here
<?php } ?>